# Adapting to the deprecation of ReactiveDataAccessStrategy

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm working on a legacy project where I need to upgrade spring boot to 2.7.18 (currently is 2.3)

When I got to the PostgreSQL part, this part of the PostgresqlDatabaseConfiguration class was deprecated and I don't know how I should change it in order to adapt to it.

public ReactiveDataAccessStrategy reactiveDataAccessStrategy(R2dbcMappingContext mappingContext,
R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions) {

```
    Assert.notNull(mappingContext, "MappingContext must not be null!");

    MappingR2dbcConverter converter = new MappingR2dbcConverter(mappingContext, r2dbcCustomConversions);

    return new DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE, converter);
}
```

I found some information in the documentation, but it's not sufficient for me to understand (I only have about 2 months of experience). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/aa3c93078eebaf8242f075594a5ead0a57115351